# two input submits, how to know which one was clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have a html site with two inputs, I added some functionality to each button with jQuery. How can I know which one is clicked?

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#form1").submit(function(event){
        if("clicked subit 1"){ //How to do this
              alert("Submit1");
        } else {
              alert("Submit2"); 
        }
    });
});
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit1" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function (event) {
      if ($(this).val() == "Submit1") {
          alert("Submit1")
      }
      else {
          alert("Submit2")
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="#">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit1" /> 
          <input type="submit" value="Submit2"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```